# Is it possible to change "cdn" folder name when I use azure account

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I know that once I enable CDN in azure it gets us link: http://mytest.cloudapp.net/cdn

Though in that case to use CDN I have to create cdn folder inside my project and put all my images inside that folder.
Is it possible to change "cdn" folder on name for example "images" and point cdn to this "images" folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instead use a URL Rewrite rule defined in your web.config. The following rule will redirect any requests made to mywebsite.com/images/.. and rewrite the uri to the CDN location. This is ideal if you already have all your images in a folder in your application and saves you having to change all the relative image paths.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="imagestoazurecdn">
      <match url="images/(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://mycdnid.vo.msecnd.net/images/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The CDN endpoint links to a storage container in Azure so all you need to do is drop all your images in there and with the above rule they will automatically get picked up in your application.

[More info on URL Rewrite here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Comment: Glad to help! I had the same problem a few months ago and this was the best solution I found with minimum changes to my app. Just one thing to mention, URL Rewrite is supported with IIS 7.5 but anything below that you will need to install the extension on the link provided. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I used this link